# Where is a small difference between result of normal finite integral and taking limit on definite integration from?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Here's my code.

```
Int1 = Integrate[((1 - Cos[x])/(L^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 1)^2) Sin[x], {x, 
   0, Pi}]
Int2 = Integrate[((1 - Cos[x])/(L^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 1)^2) Sin[x], x]
r1 = Int1[[1]];
r2 = Limit[Int2, x -> Pi] - Limit[Int2, x -> 0];
Plot[r1, {L, -1000, 1000}]
Plot[r2, {L, -1000, 1000}]
Plot[Abs[r2 - r1], {L, -1000, 1000}]
```

The results of plot r1, r2 and their difference are, respectively,
[image: r1] 
[image: [r2]]
[image: Difference]

I have results of the integration obtained by two different ways. The results are almost identical as we can see the plot of r1 and r2. Small differences are in order of $10^{-25}-10^{-24}$ which is acceptable. I want to know where the differences are from. And which one should I use for further calculation?

Comment: `FullSimplify[r1 == r2]` gives true. There's just a tiny difference in the formulas that lead to a tiny numerical difference. Use `FullSimplify[r1]` to continue, it's the same as `FullSimplify[r2]`.

Comment: Compare combinations of `Simplify` and `WorkingPrecision->128`

Comment: @Panithi If you accepted one of the answers, don't forget to also upvote it. A good rule of thumb is: Vote for all the answers you like or that helped you. Accept the one that solved your problem.

Comment: @halirutan I really want to upvote for all the answers. Unfortunately, I am still a newbie with low reputation point and system message shows "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". Thank you for all helps.

Comment: Uhh, I didn't know that you need 15 rep to vote for answers on your own question. I gave you a thumbs up for your question, so at least you are over the 15 rep boundary now :)

Comment: @halirutan Thank you. Now, I can vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Int1`, [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) with the assumption that `L` is real.

```
Int1 = Integrate[
  ((1 - Cos[x])/(L^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 1)^2) Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}] //
   FullSimplify[#, Element[L, Reals]] &

(* (-1 + 1/(1 + 2 L^2) + Log[1 + 2 L^2])/L^4 *)
```

Also `FullSimplify` `Int2`

```
Int2 = Integrate[((1 - Cos[x])/(L^2 (1 - Cos[x]) + 1)^2) Sin[x], x] // 
  FullSimplify

(* (1/(1 + L^2 - L^2 Cos[x]) + Log[1 + L^2 - L^2 Cos[x]])/L^4 *)

r2 = Limit[Int2, x -> Pi] - Limit[Int2, x -> 0]

(* -(1/L^4) + (1/(1 + 2 L^2) + Log[1 + 2 L^2])/L^4 *)
```

Then `Int1` and `r2` are equal

```
Int1 == r2 // Simplify

(* True *)

r2 - Int1 // Simplify

(* 0 *)
```